# connecting USB2.0 to USB Type C plug

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-c

I have a camera that connects to USB2.0 Type A
I would like to connect it to my laptop that has a USB Type C receptacle..

I can't use a converter.

What is the wiring diagram for this solution?

I have welded the camera's D+, D-, Vbus and GND into Type-C cable using Type-C pinout diagram
but when I connect it to my laptop the camera shuts down after a few seconds.
If I add a converter (Female C to Male A) to this cable and plug it to a Type A connection on my laptop it works with no issues.

Any advice?

Comment: Just FYI, you didn't "weld" the wires, your "soldered" them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parts that tell the laptop what kind of device has been plugged (a device, a charger, something else like a display or docking station) are missing.

Most likely you just need individual 5k1 resistors to ground on the each CC pin, but do verify yourself.

Comment: I've soldered the resistor, it works thank you!